# Converting SML to OCaml (syntax issues)

Tags: ocaml, sml

I'm ocaml absolute beginner and I'm writing some code for classes and I've got a problem with such a line:

```
datatype logicexpr = Var of string
                 | Neg of logicexpr
                 | And of logicexpr * logicexpr
                 | Or of logicexpr * logicexpr;
let rec distributeLeft(X, And(e,f)) = And(distributeLeft(X, e),distributeLeft(Y, f)) 
| Or(X, Y);;
```

Why I get a syntax error here?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: It's a part of program that converts something to CNF. I'm trying to make this code http://pastebin.com/r6QdK4my working in ocaml and I don't understand what happens inside.

Comment: Two references on SML vs OCaml: Andreas Rossberg's [Standard ML and Objective Caml, Side by Side](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/sml-vs-ocaml.html); Adam Chlipala's [Comparing Objective Caml and Standard ML](http://adam.chlipala.net/mlcomp/).

Comment: This doesn't seem like valid SML syntax either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `distributeLeft` defined by:

```
fun distributeLeft(X, And(e,f)) = And(distributeLeft(X,e),distributeLeft(X,f))
| distributeLeft(X, Y) = Or(X, Y);
```

Can be translated in OCaml to something like:

```
let rec distibuteLeft = function
  | (X, And(e,f)) -> And(distributeLeft(X,e),distributeLeft(X,f))
  | (X, Y)        -> Or(X, Y)
```

And so on ...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to really tell what you are trying to achieve, since the similarities to OCaml syntax in your code are only remote. I think you got that code you are presenting from somewhere, so maybe it would help to find out what the original language was, since it is clearly not OCaml.

Although I have no idea, what exactely you are trying to do, I can still try to give some general hints.

First: Do not use parentheses around arguments in OCaml. They are not needed and not customarily used.

```
let rec fac n = if n < 0 then 1 else n * (fac (n-1))
```

is a very common definition of the factorial function. As you can see the parameter n is used without any parentheses.

Second: It seems like you are trying to do some pattern matching. Although I do not know the language you are using it seems like this, because the code style is similar to a patter matching in haskell.

Pattern matching in OCaml needs to be done explicitly by using the `match ... with` clause. Here is an example using the data you defined:

```
type logicexpr = Var of string
               | Neg of logicexpr
               | And of logicexpr * logicexpr
               | Or of logicexpr * logicexpr

let rec distributeLeft x y = 
  match y with
    And(e,f) -> And(distributeLeft(X,e),distributeLeft(X,f))
  | Or(e,f)  -> Or(distributeLeft(X,e),distributeLeft(Y,f))
(* ... *)
```

This is just an example for the correct syntax, so do not use it. You need to really understand the program you have taken from somewhere to be able to translate it to another language. Also be very carefull, if you take for example a Haskell program a lot of algorithms will fail, because they often require special language feature, which cannot be easily translated.

So first figure out, how this program works, then get to know the syntax, and then attempt a translation. If you get stuck somewhere while doing this, just come back and maybe someone will be able to help you better.

Comment: "the similarities to OCaml syntax in your code are only remote" -> the original looks like standard ML.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Ah, thanks for the hint. I knew there was something similar to OCaml in this. However I have never looked as SML before, so I couldn't identify it. (I guess remote similarity here is subjective, of course it is not as remote as a C++ program would be)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give help with so little context (as pad is pointing out).  However, the symbol "|" isn't an operator in OCaml.  It's part of the pattern syntax.  Since we don't know what you're trying to do it's hard to say more.  *Maybe* you wanted to use "||" which is a boolean operator.  Or maybe you're trying to do something with a pattern that's not possible.

Comment: I think it should change something connected with And on somethig connected with Or and And, recursion should appear here.

Comment: @WojciechReszelewski: That is almost saying as much as nothing. Try to be more concrete, than just "should change something into something", which could describe almost any function.